# How to get the windows path from in Bash On Windows (equivalent to cygpath)?

Tags: bash, windows-10

Cygwin has `cygpath`:

```
$echo $(cygpath -pw "/cygdrive/c/users/bob/test")
$C:\users\bob\test
```

How can I achieve the same on Bash on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original accepted answer from EJK worked fine, but is outdated - to get the path (since years) just use `wslpath -w`, which will return the same windows path as cygpath for every directory that is mounted fro the windows side and will return an UNC path for everything that is only available on the WSL side:

```
$ wslpath -w ~
\\wsl.localhost\Debian\home\bob
$ wslpath -w /mnt/c/users/bob/test
C:\users\bob\test
```

For the other way around - drop the `-w` and use single quotes:

```
$ wslpath -w '\\wsl.localhost\Debian\home\bob'
/home/bob
$ wslpath 'C:\users\bob\test'
/mnt/c/users/bob/test
```

Answer (score 3):

The Windows drives are located under the `/mnt` directory, that is `c:/` is at `/mnt/c` and `d:/` is at `/mnt/d`

Thus you could use the following function (put the function in your .bashrc file)

```
function windir() {
    pwd | sed -E 's+^/mnt/(.{1})+\1:+' | sed 's+:$+:/+1' 
}
```

The first sed command translates "/mnt/c" to "c:" (or d: or whatever the drive letter is).  The second sed command handles the special case of the root directory.  I am sure there are more elegant ways to do it, but this seems to work.